# Почему не работает битбакет?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, bitbucket

Я так подозреваю что у меня одного.
просто взял и отвалился. На сайт зайти не могу, пушить тоже не могу. Остальной интернет доступен)
В браузере выдает: *Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта bitbucket.org*. во всех браузерах
В терминале:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

Роутер перезагружал, прокси настраивал, брендмауэр смотрел. Результата нет.

Может подскажите куда копнуть.

UPD: Вывод `traceroute bitbucket.org`

```
traceroute to bitbucket.org (104.192.143.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router.asus.com (192.168.1.1)  0.484 ms  1.060 ms  1.225 ms
 2  lip-b21-p8.ti.ru (212.1.254.232)  3.317 ms  3.358 ms  3.385 ms
 3  msk-r2-m40-xe-10-3-3-910.ti.ru (212.1.252.6)  3.454 ms  3.531 ms  3.594 ms
 4  krsk-r1-t13-xe-2-0-3-813.ti.ru (212.1.241.117)  28.621 ms  28.752 ms  28.872 ms
 5  s-b2-link.telia.net (213.248.93.109)  31.247 ms  31.061 ms  31.326 ms
 6  s-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.133.30)  29.447 ms s-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.119.112)  27.699 ms s-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.114.166)  28.101 ms
 7  ffm-bb3-link.telia.net (80.91.251.156)  47.041 ms ffm-bb3-link.telia.net (80.239.147.178)  47.398 ms ffm-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.139.114)  52.472 ms
 8  ffm-b4-link.telia.net (62.115.118.200)  49.512 ms ffm-b4-link.telia.net (62.115.120.4)  51.020 ms ffm-b4-link.telia.net (62.115.120.6)  53.158 ms
 9  akamai-ic-317162-ffm-b4.c.telia.net (62.115.149.23)  52.190 ms akamai-ic-317152-ffm-b4.c.telia.net (62.115.149.13)  47.234 ms akamai-ic-317162-ffm-b4.c.telia.net (62.115.149.23)  53.820 ms
10  a72-52-48-202.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (72.52.48.202)  52.677 ms a72-52-48-192.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (72.52.48.192)  50.534 ms a72-52-48-200.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (72.52.48.200)  50.699 ms
11  a72-52-48-205.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (72.52.48.205)  47.554 ms  48.083 ms a72-52-48-197.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (72.52.48.197)  47.921 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: Вчера с ним были какие-то проблемы, проверьте тут: https://status.bitbucket.org/

Comment: *"прокси настраивал"* -- вы на любую другую машину можете по ssh на порт 22 зайти? К примеру, `ssh sshtron.zachlatta.com`

Comment: да, по 22 порту прохожу

Comment: @gil9red да я даже на статус зайти не могу

Comment: Роскомнадзор мог случайно какой-нибудь айпишник вписать, провайдер мог накосячить с настройкой блокировки. [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) показывает, что сайт жив. Первое что вам должно придти в голову для исправления ситуации -- сделать tracert. Второе - проверить hosts на предмет левых записей, ну и антивирем пройтись. Третье -- попробовать зайти с соседнего компа в этой сети (попросить у мамы на секундочку или у коллеги). Потом из другой сети, допустим ноут отнести другу или в торговом центре поймать бесплатный вайфай.

Comment: @AK Добавил вывод команды traceroute, но честно сказать понял только то что смог отследить запрос до 72.52.48.205 (11 запрос)

Comment: bitbucket регулярно вот так вот отваливался-отваливался - мне это надоело и я ушел оттуда. Вам тоже советую свалить с него